# Luggage lockers at Munich central bus station (ZOB) - what are the prices and payment methods?

Tags: luggage-storage, munich

My friend will be arriving Munich Hbf on Saturday 1000. He has a Flixbus to Prag at 2345. The [official ZOB website](https://www.muenchen-zob.de/en/faq) states that lockers are available. I have a few questions:

1. What are the prices for these lockers?
2. Are they manned lockers? I mean is there a person handling the process?
3. If not, should he be carrying the exact change to use these lockers? And does it have English user manual in addition to German on these lockers?

He thought it was better to drag the luggage to ZOB in the morning itself rather than use the lockers in Hbf.

Comment: What do you mean with 'timings for these lockers'?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo - I meant to ask the timings when they can be accessed.

Answer (score 2):

The rules are pretty much the same for main station and ZOB.

1. The lockers are not manned (never seen that in Germany anywhere)
2. Prices are "a few Euros" - Maybe 2 Euros for 4 hours and more for longer.
3. Carrying change is recommended. Germany is a cash country. As a travel you should try to always have coins and small notes ready for convenience.

Answer (score -3):

The [MVV website](http://www.mvv-muenchen.de/en/service/luggage-storage/index.html) provides some more detail on the luggage storage at München HBF. To answer your specific questions:

1. The lockers are accessible 24 hours
2. They are not manned. You can choose your own locker (provided it is free of course) and you handle your luggage on your own
3. It is recommended to carry the exact change as they most likely do not provide change. You can find the prices on the MVV website and on the ZOB website you linked to. The instructions are usually in both languages (with pictures).

Comment: The question is about the lockers at ZOB (the bus station at Hackerbrücke S-Bahn station) but you answered for the central train station (Hauptbahnhof or Hbf). Presumabely (going by the pages you and OP linked) they are interested in the ZOB lockers because they are cheaper.

Comment: @Jan - Yes, we are interested in the lockers at the ZOB but not just because they are cheaper (which I notice only now :)). He believes it will be easy for him to retrieve the luggage just before the bus arrives (in case there is a delay). Else he needs to plan the transport from Hbf to ZOB late at night with luggage and does not want to be stressed.

Comment: @DarthVader The route from Hbf to ZOB is either around ten minutes on foot just down the road or one station with literally any westbound suburban train (S-Bahn). You can also take a tram for two stops or so. However, unless you already have a ticket I would not want to spend the extra €1.20 or what it is now for that one stop. ;)